# Code missing after git fetch --all and git checkout from specific tag

Tags: git, gitlab

In Linux server, I want to update my code from tag `v1.0` to `v1.1`. I did following steps manually to update my code.

- git reset --hard HEAD
- git fetch --all
- git checkout v1.1
- sudo git checkout v1.1

Then when I check with `git status`, it shows following file as modified.

```
# HEAD detached at v1.1
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   app/Console/backend.php
```

And also, the updated code of v1.1 is not really exists when I check with `cat app/Console/backend.php` command.

But, when I check with `git diff HEAD app/Console/backend.php`, it shows updated code from v1.1

```
diff --git a/app/Console/backend.php b/app/Console/backend.php
index 9b288d8..38c6846 100644
--- a/app/Console/backend.php
+++ b/app/Console/backend.php
@@ -45,9 +45,5 @@ class BackendServer
                 }
             }
         }
-
-        // code ...
-        $schedule->command('somecommand')->daily()->at('00:00');
-
     }
 }
```

I'm confuse with it. Normally, if `git status` shows as modified, then codes are really exists in source code file. But, this time some of the code is not really exists in code file and can only see with `git diff` command.

I don't understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: Run `git ls-files -v $path` to check the status of the file in which some code line is missing. If the output line starts with a lowercase `h`, the file is marked as assume unchanged. If so, you could further run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged $path` to cancel the effect and then run `git status` or `git diff` to see if it's actually modified.

Comment: it shows uppercase `H`

Comment: `sudo git checkout v1.1` this is wrong on so many levels. Don't do this.